# Using virt-install to setup an Ubuntu 12.04 VM

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-12.04, rhel, kvm

I am trying to set up an Ubuntu precise image with this command:

```
virt-install --virt-type kvm --name precise --ram 1024 --cdrom=/data/isos/precise-64-mini.iso --disk /tmp/precise.qcow2,format=qcow2 --network network=default --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole --os-type=linux --os-variant=ubuntuprecise
```

But I get this error every time:

```
ERROR    OS variant 'ubuntuprecise' does not exist in our dictionary for OS type 'linux'
```

And I noticed that 'ubuntuprecise' is not listed in the variant lists. Is there any way to add/update the list or is there an alternative to use?